# On proving right-continuity of a distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions, proof-writing

I am unsecure regarding my proof on right-continuity of the distribution function.

Let $\epsilon >0$.

By continuity from above of the measure $P$ we have $G_{n} \downarrow G \implies P(G_{n}) \downarrow P(G)$ where $x_{n} \downarrow x$ means $x_{n}  \rightarrow x$ and $x_{n+1} \le x_{n}$ for real numbers . $G_{n} \downarrow G$ means $G_{n+1} \subset G_{n}$ and $G=\cap G_{n}$ for sets.  By letting $G_{n}=(-\infty,x+\frac{1}{n}]$ and $G=(-\infty,x]$ we get,

$\mid P( X\le x+\frac{1}{n})-P( X\le x) \mid < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$ for some large $N$.

as $\cap_{n} (-\infty,x+\frac{1}{n}]=(-\infty,x]$ which follows by the following argument,

Suppose $y \in  (-\infty,x+\frac{1}{n}]$ for all $n$ and $y \notin (-\infty,x]$. Then $y \in \cap_{n} (x,x+\frac{1}{n}]$  which is a contradiction as this is the empty set. The remaining inclusion $\cap_{n} (-\infty,x+\frac{1}{n}] \supset(-\infty,x]$ is trival.

Given an arbitrary sequence $x_{m} \rightarrow x$ we can take $\delta =\frac{1}{N}$ where $x_{m} < x+\frac{1}{N}$ for all $m>M$

This $\delta$ satisfies the condition for right-continuity since for any $x_{m} < x+\frac{1}{n}$, $F(x_{m})$ is even closer to $F(x)$ then $F(x+\frac{1}{N})$ by monotonocity of $F$.

Thus $F(x)=P(X\le x)$ is right continous.

Comment: @nicomezi well its not really the same kind of continuty I assume continuty of measures w.r.t decreasing sets. But still the step is not far going from one to the other,

Comment: I don't think you can start like that because continuity is stronger than right-continuity. If you start like that, you basically start by assuming right-continuity.

Comment: @Elsa look at my comment on the other comment!

Comment: @user21312 What you wrote in your comment, I think this is the way to go, using a sequence of decreasing sets and the properties of measures.

Comment: @nicomezi oh, what do you think one shuold write then? $P$ is still a measure

Comment: Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480042/prove-that-the-cdf-of-a-random-variable-is-always-right-continuous/480097#480097)

Comment: @nicomezi nice! well "arash" proof is the same as mine imo. Where he writes "Now , for each $\epsilon$, you can find $n$ such that...." is the same as assuing continuity of the measure right?

Comment: The step "By continuity of $P( X\le x)$" takes for granted the conclusion. It even takes for granted a stronger property, which does not always hold. Thus, no proof at all here.

Comment: Arash answer does not provide a full proof. Have a look at the question post.

Comment: @Did do you mean that the argument is total nonsense or that it is so trival that there is nothing to prove?

Comment: The edit "By continuity of the measure $P( X\le x)$" does not help. What do you mean exactly there?

Comment: @Did https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Properties   the last property "continuity from above"

Comment: Yes, but the problem is **how you suggest to use this property**. At present, your phrasing is much too vague.

Comment: @Did I made some clarifying defintions(I hope) to adress you comment

Comment: What are the events $F_n$ and $F$ used here? Please include a proof that "your" $F$ satisfies $F=\bigcap\limits_nF_n$ for "your" $F_n$s.

Comment: Remains to show that your $G$ is indeed $G=\bigcap\limits_nG_n$...

Comment: @Did It should be complete now.

Comment: I think you mean "continuity from above of the measure $P$", not "...the measure $P(X \leq x)$".

Comment: The rest of your argument is hard to follow. You have established (more or less) that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}F(x + 1/n) = F(x)$. Why does this imply that $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to x^+}F(y) = F(x)$? You will need to use the monotonicity of $F$.

Comment: @Bungo I think I dont need that since the convergce of $P(G_{n})$ to $P(G)$ is monotone

Comment: Convergence of $P(G_n)$ to $P(G)$ is equivalent to $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}F(x+1/n) = F(x)$. This shows that for one particular sequence $x_n = x+1/n$ converging to $x$, we have $\lim F(x_n) = F(x)$. For a general function $F$ this would not imply right continuity. You need to exploit the monotonicity of $F$. This argument is missing.

Comment: @Bungo Does the monotone convergnce "$\downarrow$" really only give me the limit?

Comment: Continuity from above of the measure $P$ is a statement about **sequences** of sets (it exploits **countable** additivity of a measure). You have used it to establish $F(x + s_n) \to F(x)$ for one particular **sequence** $s_n = 1/n$. To establish right continuity of $F$ you need to show that $F(x+s)$ becomes arbitrarily close to $F(x)$ for **all** sufficiently small $s > 0$, not just when we constrain ourselves to the particular choice $s_n = 1/n$.

Comment: @Bungo I updated it. It should be soild now right?